# Objective C Threading Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here's the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < personListViewController.peopleCount; i++) {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getPerson:) toTarget:self withObject:i];
}
```

getPerson looks like this:

```
 - (void)getPerson:(int)whichPerson { }
```

When I build this, I get the following :**warning: passing argument 3 of 'detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:' makes pointer from integer without a cast**

All I want to do is pass an int to getPerson via detachNewThreadSelector and I can't figure out how the heck to get it to take anything but an object pointer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The selector you pass as the first argument to `-[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:]` must take a single argument which is of type `id` (a pointer to an object instance). Although you can play games with the fact that (on most platforms), a pointer is the same size as an `int` and type cast your value into an `id` and then back to an `int`, you should not rely on this behavior. Instead, write a wrapper method that takes an `NSNumber` argument and wrap your `int` in an `NSNumber`. The wrapper method implementation could be:

```
- (void)getPersonWithNumber:(NSNumber*)number {
  [self getPerson:[number integerValue]];
}
```

Your loop would then be

```
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < personListViewController.peopleCount; i++) {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getPersonWithNumber:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i];
}
```

Note that I've converted from `int` to `NSInteger` throughout. Unless you are interfacing with legacy code that uses `int`, you should use `NSInteger` which is a typedef for the appropriate size integer on each platform (32 or 64-bit) in new Cocoa code.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you a million times over. It's always the small things that trip me up in objective-c.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the integer in an NSNumber class, to make the number an object.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getPerson:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
```

NSThread doesn't take primitives (like int or char), so you have to use NSNumber!

Hope that helps.